# check and uncheck the control without using the mouse,as when we hit enter key the button control gets triggered

Tags: javascript, html

Currently i have a html design wherein which there is a textbox and a button..after typing the id on pressing enter the page will get redirect,but at the same time there is also a checkbox control.

My question is :

Is there any option to check and uncheck the control without using the mouse,as when we hit enter key the button control gets triggered

For more idea ,i have given a signin window of gmail which contains a textbox and checkbox

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, there is none without involving JavaScript. You can tabulate to the checkbox and check or uncheck it using the space bar, though. Don't forget to consider also that you should not check anything like 'I accept the terms/cookies' on behalf of your user, as this should be explicit agreement unless you have explicitly specified it.

Comment: hitting enter key will trigger the submit button of the form you are currenlty focused in to.  Pressing tab will transfer the focus from one field to another but the enter key will always trigger the submit button of the form.

Comment: i have edited the tag : javascript..kindly hav a glimpse and share idea

Comment: @robwaminal ,thank you rob but is there any way to do the same without mouse for check and uncheck

Comment: You can press space to trigger the checkbox, if it is focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hitting enter key will trigger the submit button of the form you are currenlty focused in to.  Pressing tab will transfer the focus from one field to another but the enter key will always trigger the submit button of the form.

But you can trap the keypress when hitting enter and perform the check/uncheck instead of the default trigger.

```
$("form").keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // code that check/uncheck your checkbox
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will click the button regardless of where the "Enter" happens on the page:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        $("#Your_Submit_Button_ID").click();
    }
});
```